# Not able to create a dataframe within a function

Tags: python, dataframe

I am not able to create a new dataframe df111 in the function below.

```
def term_frequency_new(term, tokenized_document): 
    codelistWord=[]
    codelistCount=[]
    for item in term:
        codelistWord.append(item)
        codelistCount.append(tokenized_document.count(item))    
    print(codelistWord) 
    print(codelistCount)
    df111=pd.DataFrame({'Words':codelistWord,'Freq':codelistCount})
```

Comment: What's the error mesage?

Comment: have you tried accessing df111 in the function, it only exists in the scope of the function so wont be accessible outside of the function unless returned or assigned to a global variable

Comment: At pointed out above scope might be an issue. Also, if you are just calculating the frequency [Counter][1]

Counter 
  [1]: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter might be very useful and may reduce some lines of code

Comment: the error message is that the df111 is not defined

Comment: declare it global. you might be accessing outside the funtion

Answer (score 1):

When trying to access without a global variable

```
from collections import Counter
def create_df(lis):
    df111 =pd.DataFrame(Counter(lis), index=[0])
create_df(['a','a','b'])
```

> df111.head() # Gives error as it is not within the scope

With global

```
from collections import Counter
global df111
def create_df(lis):
    global df111
    df111 =pd.DataFrame(Counter(lis), index=[0])
create_df(['a','a','b'])
```

Now you can access the df111 variable

```
df111.head() #Should print the data
    a   b
0   2   1
```